# node-sass - sass_context_wrapper.h:8:10: fatal error: sass/context.h: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I am trying to install [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)  but failed with the error below. I tried to [rebuild](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1764) command but no luck at all - `sudo npm rebuild node-sass`

```
$ npm install node-sass     

...
...
...
gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture x64
gyp verb node dev dir /home/lau/.node-gyp/10.12.0
gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/var/www/html/projects/autopoiesis/autopoiesis/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
  g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/home/lau/.node-gyp/10.12.0/include/node -I/home/lau/.node-gyp/10.12.0/src -I/home/lau/.node-gyp/10.12.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/lau/.node-gyp/10.12.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/lau/.node-gyp/10.12.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/lau/.node-gyp/10.12.0/deps/zlib -I/home/lau/.node-gyp/10.12.0/deps/v8/include -I../../../../nan  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++1y -std=c++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp
In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:3:0:
../src/sass_context_wrapper.h:8:10: fatal error: sass/context.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sass/context.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
binding.target.mk:116: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/var/www/html/projects/autopoiesis/autopoiesis/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/var/www/html/projects/autopoiesis/autopoiesis/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-36-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/www/html/projects/autopoiesis/autopoiesis/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/html/projects/autopoiesis/autopoiesis/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN website@0.1.0 No description
npm WARN website@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN website@0.1.0 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lau/.npm/_logs/2019-05-18T01_33_09_744Z-debug.log
```

Any ideas why? What can I do?

Comment: That is an old version that does't support Node 10. I would suggest you upgrade node-sass if you want to use Node 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to install it with `LIBSASS_EXT="no" npm install` (remove `node_modules` folder to trigger the `node-sass` build, but be aware of the removement) - basically you have to check your `libsass` installation. Did you install `libsass` on your machine? On Mac it would be `brew install libsass` or on [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849057/how-to-install-libsass-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I dont think I have libsass install. I am on Linux Ubuntu. Should I install globally or locally?

Comment: I just tried that command and it seems to be working with some warnings

Comment: nice, but that should only be a workaround. you have to install libsass. would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted as it works now.

Comment: I should install that with `sudo npm install -g libsass` globally, right?

Comment: I get an error for installing it `npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: libsass@latest`

Comment: you do not install that with npm, because it's a system component - there are instructions on how to do that on ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/849057/how-to-install-libsass-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 4):

Recent Ubuntu versions have package `libsass-dev` available in default repositories (tested on Ubuntu 20.04)

Just run following for the rescue:

```
sudo apt-get install libsass-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

LIBSASS_EXT="no" npm i